# Inconsistency between limit and small-angle approximation

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have the following two relations
\begin{equation}
\sin^{2}\phi_{1}=\alpha_{1}\tan\frac{\theta}{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sin^{2}\phi_{2}=\frac{2\alpha_{2}}{\sin\theta}\Bigg(1-\cos\theta\cos^{2}\frac{\phi_{1}}{2}\Bigg)
\end{equation}

where, $1<\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}<2$.

Now if we take $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\sin^{2}\phi_{1}$ then the R.H.S of the first equation becomes zero since $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\alpha_{1}\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\alpha_{1}\frac{\theta}{2}=0$. Thus,in the limit of $\theta$ going to zero, $\phi_{1}$ also goes to zero.

Therefore, we can conclude that $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\sin^{2}\frac{\phi_{1}}{2}=\lim_{\phi_{1}\rightarrow 0}\sin^{2}\frac{\phi_{1}}{2}=0$ and $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\cos^{2}\frac{\phi_{1}}{2}=\lim_{\phi_{1}\rightarrow 0}\cos^{2}\frac{\phi_{1}}{2}=1$.

Now, if we take the limit in the second equation then we have the following scenario.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\sin^{2}\phi_{2} & = \lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0,\phi_{1}\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\alpha_{2}}{\sin\theta}\Bigg(1-\cos\theta\cos^{2}\frac{\phi_{1}}{2}\Bigg)\\
& = \lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\alpha_{2}}{\sin\theta}\Bigg(1-\cos\theta\Bigg)\\
& = 2\alpha_{2}\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\\
& = 0
\end{align*}

Therefore, if $\theta$ goes to zero $\phi_{1}$ goes to zero, consequently $\phi_{2}$ also goes to zero.

Now, we will do small-angle approximation to see when $\phi_{1}$ is small $\phi_{2}$ is small or not. Since, $\theta$ being small implies $\phi_{1}$ being small we can take $\sin^{2}\phi_{1}\approx \phi_{1}^{2}$, $\alpha_{1}\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\approx \alpha_{1}\frac{\theta}{2}$. Using these approximations the first equation can be written as
\begin{equation}
\phi_{1}^{2}\approx \alpha_{1}\frac{\theta}{2}.
\end{equation}
Similarly, we also have $\sin\theta\approx \theta$ and $\cos\theta\approx \Big(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}\Big)$ and $\cos\frac{\phi_{1}}{2}\approx 1-\frac{\phi^{2}_{1}}{8}=1-\alpha_{1}\frac{\theta}{16}$

Omitting all the $\theta^{3}$ and higher order terms we can write
\begin{align}
\sin^{2}\phi_{2}& \approx \frac{2\alpha_{2}}{\theta}\Bigg(1-\Big(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{\phi^{2}_{1}}{8}\Big)^{2}\Bigg)\\
& = \frac{2\alpha_{2}}{\theta}\Bigg(1-\Big(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}\Big)\Big(1-\alpha_{1}\frac{\theta}{16}\Big)^{2}\Bigg)\\
& \approx \frac{2\alpha_{2}}{\theta}\Bigg(1-\Big(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}\Big)\Big(1+\alpha_{1}^{2}\frac{\theta^{2}}{256}-\alpha_{1}\frac{\theta}{8}\Big)\Bigg)\\
& = 2\alpha_{2}\Bigg(\frac{\alpha_{1}}{8}+\frac{\theta}{2}-\alpha_{1}\frac{\theta^{2}}{16}-\alpha^{2}_{1}\frac{\theta}{256}\Bigg).
\end{align}
In the last equation we have omitted all the terms higher than or equal to $\theta^{3}$. Due to the existence of a constant term $\frac{\alpha_{1}}{8}$, $\sin^{2}\phi_{2}$ is not small, which is inconsistent with the inference drawn from taking the limit of $\theta$ going to zero.

Can anyone help me point out where the fallacy is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first term of your approximation is correct, but rather the limit of $\sin^2 \phi_2$ as $\theta\to 0$ is not $0$. The limit should be $\alpha_1 \alpha_2/4$.

Comment: Note that $\phi_1$ depends on $\theta$, so you cannot make it "tend to zero first" and then evaluate the rest of the limit. You have to make them "tend to zero simultaneously".

Comment: As a toy example, consider $\phi_1=\theta$. Now try to compute $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \phi_1/\theta$. If you let $\phi_1$ tend to $0$ first, then the expression becomes $0$, but clearly the result should be $1$.

Comment: I understood what you are saying instead of $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0,\phi\rightarrow 0}$ we can express $\cos^{2}\frac{\phi}{2}$ in terms of $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ and take its limit. Doing that yields $\frac{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}}{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I would provide a full-fledged answer.

As in my comments, $\phi_1$ depends on $\theta$,
so they cannot be treated as two independent variables.
The limit of $\sin^2 \phi_2$ is incorrectly calculated.

Here's one way to do it.
Note that when $|\theta|$ is small,
we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sin^2(\phi_1/2) &= \frac{1-\cos(\phi_1)}{2} = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-\alpha_1\tan(\theta/2)}}{2} \\
\cos^2(\phi_1/2) &= \frac{1+\cos(\phi_1)}{2} = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha_1\tan(\theta/2)}}{2}
\end{align*}
$$
For sufficiently small $\theta\neq 0$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1-\cos\theta \cos^2 (\phi_1/2)}{\sin\theta}
&= \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\cos^2(\phi_1/2) + \frac{1-\cos^2(\phi_1/2)}{\sin\theta} \\
&= \tan (\theta/2) \cos^2(\phi_1/2) + \frac{1-\sqrt{1-\alpha_1\tan(\theta/2)}}{2\sin\theta} \\
&= \tan (\theta/2) \frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha_1\tan(\theta/2)}}{2} \\
&\quad + 
\frac{\theta/2}{2\sin\theta}
\frac{\alpha_1\tan(\theta/2)}{\theta/2}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\alpha_1\tan(\theta/2)}}{\alpha_1\tan(\theta/2)}
\end{align*}
$$
Now, each component is convergent and we know their limits,
so we can compute them separately and combine them together (this is one of the few scenarios where you can do it separately).
This gives us
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{2\alpha_2(1-\cos\theta \cos^2 (\phi_1/2))}{\sin\theta}
= 2\alpha_2 \cdot \frac{\alpha_1}{8} = \frac{\alpha_1\alpha_2}{4},
\end{align*}
$$
which is consistent with the approximation.